# Tree show expand symbol when children array is empty

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using the tabulator tree js library (http://tabulator.info/). But why is the tree show the expand symbol even if the children array is empty? This is very annoying! Is it a bug?

This:

```
var tdata = [{id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", "_children":[]},];
```

Results in this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as have seen , if you have a "_children" array (even if its empty) and your "dataTree" is set to true , then you will have the expand button always visible .

actually it is an opened [issue](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3211) in the tabulator repo ...

so there is only one solution here or work arround ,

you can try to not provide the _children array when there is no children ( backend )
or adjust it in the front end using js

```js
var tdata = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Billy Bob",
    age: "12",
    _children: []
  }
];

tdata.forEach((e) => {
  if (!e._children.length) delete e._children; //this will delete any empty _children element 
});
```

here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-thunder-8fc58?file=/src/index.js) ( it has two rows one with children one without , try and remove the for each and expriment with it )

Answer (score 0):

I found what is the cause. You need to remove "**dataTree:true,**" part from creating **new Tabulator** object.

Comment: what about multiple data rows ,, ones have children and ones dont ? you disabled it for everyrow if you remove it or set it to false ... that dosnt work

Comment: For that case, you need to remove **"_children":[]** property from the tabledata when you use "dataTree:true". If you have "_children" property in the tabledata together with "dataTree: true" in "Tabulator" object, it'll automatically add dataTreeExpandElement to that row to show this row is expected to have children.

Comment: yes thats exactly what i did , read my answer . 
if you remove the datatree prop then even if you have children they wont display .

Comment: Actually, that is not my question. As shown in the question, he didn't mention that he want to used mixed types. I'm giving a solution to what he asks exactly.

Comment: first they are the same types second removing it will limit the features of tabulator . 
finally yours cant be the exact  answser to what he asked for coz a google search will tell him that he can disable the tabletree ,, its in the documentation of tabulator .

Comment: What's your problem in here? There is no point for comparing. How you're so sure on this **"a google search will tell him that he can disable the tabletree"**. Are you the same one who is asking the question? If you want to discuss, why you go and discuss with OP. Proving one's answer wrong will not make yours right more. It will depends on individual. So, different people will find helpful on different answers.

Comment: sorry for that , i asked you even tho i answered it already coz i thought i was wrong for a second and i responded later because you said its the exact answer i had to read the question again , its not me proving you wrong i m trying to make sure my answer is right and yes some may find it benificial if they want to remove the tree feature

Comment: It's okay. I replied in you second comment which is exactly same as your answer but you deleted the children with loop. When you commented first, I thought you're the OP and I told you the another way if you don't want to remove "dataTree:true" which was same as your asnwer. I thought I also misunderstood because I feel you're asking me already answered one in yours. Sorry too man.

Comment: its okay man , thanks for being comprehensive and i am sorry again for any inconveniences

Comment: Same to you man. Sorry for any inconveniences, too!